# Can't build project after moving workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, build, buildpath, .class-file

I have moved my workspace in `Eclipse`. Everything is fine except I can't build my project. If I delete the contents of `bin` and try to get the `.class` files back by building, no error message will be displayed but the `bin` folder will remain empty.

I've checked my old workspace location and it's empty after the build attempt as well.

How do I remedy this?

Comment: Eclipse has a 'problems' window that shows workspace issues. Does that show any messages?

Comment: Get Eclipse to prompt for a workspace, by going to Preferences then to General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Workspaces. Check the box labelled "Prompt for workspace on startup". Restart, point to the new location for workspace and it *should* fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This would be due to your eclipse still pointing to the old workspace. Which version of Eclipse are you using? In Juno and Kepler, as Nicolás Carlo said, take Window->Preferences. In the Preferences window take General->Startup and Shutdown->Workspaces. You can either check "Prompt for workspace on startup" or remove the old workspace and give the new one in the window. This should fix your problem.